# How to pass a variable string to a file txt at the biginig of test?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem

I Have a program general like this gene.sh

that for all file (es file: geneX.csv) make a directory with the name of gene (example: Genex/geneX.csv) next this program compile an other program inside gene.sh but this progrm need a varieble and I dont know how do it.

this is the program gene.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a dictory for each file *.xls and *.csv

for fname in *.xlsx *csv
    do
            dname=${fname%.*}

            [[ -d $dname ]] || mkdir "$dname"
            mv "$fname" "$dname"
    done

# For each gene go inside the directory and compile the programs  getChromosomicPositions.sh to have the positions, and getHapolotipeStings.sh to have the variants

for geni in */; do
    cd $geni
    z=$(tail -n 1 *.csv | tr ';'  "\n" | wc -l)
    cd ..
    cp getChromosomicPositions.sh $geni ---> 
    cp getHaplotypeStrings.sh $geni
    cd $geni
    export z
    ./getChromosomicPositions.sh *.csv
    export z
    ./getHaplotypeStrings.sh *.csv
    cd ..
done
```

This is the program getChromosomichPositions.sh:

```
rm chrPosRs.txt

grep '^Haplotype\ ID' $1 | cut -d ";" -f 4-61 | tr ";" "\n" | awk '{print "select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name=\""$1"\";"}' > listOfQuery.txt

while read l; do

    echo $l > query.txt
    mysql -h genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -u genome -A -D hg38 --skip-column-names < query.txt > queryResult.txt

    if [[ "$(cat queryResult.txt)" == "" ]];
    then    

        cat query.txt |
        while read line; do
                echo $line | awk '$6 ~/rs/ {print $6}' > temp.txt;
                if [[ "$(cat temp.txt)" != "" ]];
                        then cat temp.txt | awk -F'name="' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/";//g' > temp.txt;
            ./getHGSVposHG19.sh temp.txt ---> Hear the problem--->
                else
                        echo $line | awk '{num=sub(/.*:g\./,"");num+=sub(/\".*/,"");if(num==2){print};num=""}' > temp2.txt
                fi
        done
        cat query.txt >> varianti.txt
        echo "Missing Data" >> chrPosRs.txt
    else
        cat queryResult.txt >> chrPosRs.txt
    fi

done < listOfQuery.txt

rm query*
```

hear the problem:

I need to enter in the file temp.txt and put automatically at the beginning of the file the variable $geni of the program gene.sh

How can I do that?

Comment: for example in temp.txt there is:

35941G>A

I wont through the variable $geni (ex: geni="CBA1") change the file temp.txt in:

CBA1:35941G>A

Comment: Can not you edit your question in stead of commenting it ? And while you are at it, you could correct the formatting, notably the `!#/bin/bash` line. \[EDIT] You corrected the line while I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass `"$geni"` as say the first argument when invoking your script, and treating the rest of the arguments as your expected .csv files.

`./getChromosomicPositions.sh "$geni" *.csv`

Alternatively, you can set it as environment variable for the script, so that it can be used there (or just export it).

`geni="$geni" ./getChromosomicPositions.sh *.csv`

In any case, once you have it available in the second script, you can do

if passed as the first argument:

`echo "${1}:$(cat temp.txt | awk -F'name="' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/";//g')`

or if passed as environment variable:

`echo "${geni}:$(cat temp.txt | awk -F'name="' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/";//g')`

Comment: I really thenks you for the halp but i tryed both of the commands but in the same case they don't work, how can I do